# in JavaScript searching a string for end of line

Tags: javascript

My problem involves using JavaScript in a gmail sheet to search emails using getRawContent.

I've been using `indexOf` to get a particular data from the string, I'm able to find the starting point for the data I want to use.

For example `var startxmailer = rawmail.indexOf("X-Mailer: ",0);`, but I'm unable to identify or locate end of line/carriage return to give me an end point to use sub-string to get the data for example `var allxmailer = rawmail.substring(endxmailer,test1);`.

I've tried `indexOf(/[\n,\r]/,0)` and `(/\r,\n,|\r|,\n,\$,\O,\x/)`.
I've put the section of text into a variable in the script and used the above to locate end of line/carriage return but not been to successful any assistance would be much appreciated as I would like to be able to different section of data from a email in Raw Content.

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't work with regular expressions, but you can use `exec` or `match`. However, have you simply tried `.indexOf('\n');` ?

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions, instead of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) you should use [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xmailer = (rawmail.match(/X-Mailer: (.*)/i) || [])[1];
```

This will get the content of the `X-Mailer` header into the `xmailer` variable, or `undefined` if no such header was found. This works because `.` explicitly matches everything that isn't a new line.